# Using a homemade function in a dplyr pipeline generating an unused argument error

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Here's a reproducible mini version of my dataset:

```
trial <- c(rep(1,25), rep(2, 25), rep(3, 25))
minitime <- c(1:25)
time <- c(rep(minitime, 3))
X <- c(runif(75))
Y <- c(runif(75))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(trial, time, X, Y))
```

I wrote a function a little while ago to calculate a point by point change in Y, as such:

```
df$Y2 <- df$Y

shift <- function(x, n){
c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}

df$Y2 <- shift(df$Y2, 1)
df$velocity <- df$Y2 - df$Y1
```

Normally I use this function trial by trial, and then bind those trials into a master dataset, but I recently had to transform my entire dataset, so I need to calculate this change in Y on the dataset as a whole. I need to group by trial, apply the function and then generate my change in Y. I tried to do this in dplyr as such:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(trial) %>%
shift(Y2, 1) %>%
mutate(velocity == Y2 - Y1)
```

and it generated an error "Error in shift(., x = Y2, n = 1) : unused argument (.)" and I don't know what is up with this error. If there's some kind of issue with using my function in a pipeline, or if there's a better way to do this, please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Y1` is not a column in `df`, do you mean `Y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think you tried to do the following:

```r
library(dplyr)

trial <- c(rep(1,25), rep(2, 25), rep(3, 25))
minitime <- c(1:25)
time <- c(rep(minitime, 3))
X <- c(runif(75))
Y <- c(runif(75))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(trial, time, X, Y))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  mutate(Y2 = lead(Y, 1),
         velocity = Y2 - Y)

head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   trial [1]
#>   trial  time       X      Y     Y2 velocity
#>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1     1 0.757   0.118  0.174    0.0565
#> 2     1     2 0.686   0.174  0.0533  -0.121 
#> 3     1     3 0.219   0.0533 0.322    0.269 
#> 4     1     4 0.243   0.322  0.0700  -0.252 
#> 5     1     5 0.158   0.0700 0.738    0.668 
#> 6     1     6 0.00458 0.738  0.323   -0.415
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As @Rui Barradas mentions in the comments: your `shift` function would also work:

```r
 df <- df %>%
  group_by(trial) %>%
  mutate(Y2 = shift(Y, 1),
         velocity = Y2 - Y)
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants `lead`, not `lag`. `shift` where you use `lag` would work. Upvote, anyway.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I realized later that lead() accomplishes more or less the same thing as shift(), but either one works in the pipeline now. Sorry about the Y1 vs Y confusion as well. Pipeline works great.